# Lock file issue

Tags: windows, file, visual-c++, locking

With Windows7. I create an exclusive file :

```
int id = open("c:\\data.lck", O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR);
```

In the explorer, I see my new file with RACI attributes
Why the flag "R" for read-only !? I don't understand.

Now I stop my prog, and run another one which does:

```
remove("c:\\data.lck");
```

The function fails, the file is not deleted...
...But I still can remove it from the explorer !?

Basically I used to think that when a process dies, it releases all its lock on files.
So why the remove() failed ??

By the way, I'm compiling against VS2010, and all the program are running with the same user within the same session.

Comment: Not sure why it gets the read only attribute. But you cannot delete a read only file. You have to clear the read only attribute first. That's what explorer does.

Comment: I do see it turn on the readonly attribute, but only if the O_CREATE | S_IWRITE options are turned on.  Some crazy *nix semantics mapping I guess.

Comment: Ok, find the answer herer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412625/why-is-the-read-only-attribute-set-sometimes-for-files-created-by-my-service